# Play framework Json output issue

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a simple action which outputs a json object string, like this:

```
Ok(toJson(Map(
  "results" -> result_lists
)))
```

This works all right. But if I do:

```
Ok(toJson(Map(
  "action" -> action_string, // a Scala String
  "results" -> result_lists  // a Scala List
)))
```

I got

> No Json serializer found for type scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable]

compilation error...what's the problem?

Comment: Well... do first of all... what is the type of `Map("action" -> action,
  "results" -> result_lists)`. You see... `toJsoe(Map(
  "results" -> result_lists
)))` worked because Play provides Json serializer for Map, List, String, Int, Double etc. So basically if a Json serializer is availiable for type `T1` and `T2` then you can Json serialize a `Map[ T1, List[ T2 ] ]`. I hope you understand it now.

Comment: What's type of action? You have to provide Writes[TypeOfAction] like described here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson#Using-Writes-converters

Comment: Hi both, I added comments to indicate the types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have posted in the comments before, the type of the Map is not something which can be deserialized into Json by the framework, but you can easily get rid of the Map:

```
scala> val s = "hello"
s: String = hello

scala> val list = List(1,2,3)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> Json.obj("somestring" -> s, "somemap" -> list)
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"somestring":"hello","somemap":[1,2,3]}
```

The resulting object can then be returned by the action as desired.