# unable to convert scala map to json with play 2

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

i have a case class signup with an optional variable "secondaryEmail"

```
case class SignUp(firstNname : String, 
                  var lastName: String, 
                  var email: String,
                  var secondryEmail : Option[String]
                  )
```

i want to convert it to Json for that i have written a function to convert it into a Map

```
def putInMap(obj: SignUp) = {

    val signupMap = Map(
        "firstname" -> obj.firstNname,
        "lastname" -> obj.lastName,
        "email" -> obj.email,
        "secondryemail" -> Some(obj.secondryEmail)
        )
        signupMap
  }
```

Now when i try to convert it to Json like this

```
val signupjson = Json.toJson(putInMap(SignUp))
```

it gives me this error

**No Json serializer found for type scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.**

is there any other way of solving this error or i have to implement an implicit Write for this?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890354/play-framework-json-output-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thing that you shoul change your code by this:

```
def putInMap(obj: SignUp) = {

    val signupMap = Map(
        "firstname" -> obj.firstNname,
        "lastname" -> obj.lastName,
        "email" -> obj.email,
        "secondryemail" -> obj.secondryEmail.getOrElse("")
        )
        signupMap
   }
```

Use getOrElse to access a value or a default when no value is present: the empty String or what a string of you want,

if not you should try tow write the implicit methods writes for parsing the Json as suggested by play framework documentation in Using Writes converters at this [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson) do not forget to use .writeNullable for the Option[String] field

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to a map in the first place.

```
implicit val signupWriter = Json.writes[SignUp]
val up = SignUp("Jo", "B", "foo@mail.com", None)
val json = Json.toJson(up)
```

And it will output a `JsValue` for you.

Comment: can you please tell me if i have an enum in the Signup class then how can i use your code above?